# How cookies affect Varnish caching?

Tags: php, cookies, google-analytics, varnish, adobe-analytics

How does Varnish caching affect third-party cookies set by Omniture and first-party cookies set by Google Analytics?

So far I've seen opposing opinions, some people say that because the tracking stats are created by JavaScript (which is true), that stripping these Cookies from the request won't affect GA or Omniture.

However [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871283/how-do-tracking-cookies-work) they are saying that these softwares set various cookies to track recurring visitors, and so stripping these cookies from the request would essentially count every user as a new visitor.

I don't want my users to count every time as a new visitor. I am not sure either that these JavaScript embeds have the ability to calculate if the page is being served to a first time or recurring visitor. Any links to offical GA or Omniture documentation is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Google Analytics uses first party cookies, not third party cookies.

Comment: Edited question to reflect that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics sets cookies through javascript on your domain. See [How Google Analytics uses cookies](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html#HowGAUsesCookies) :

> Google Analytics uses only first-party
>   cookies. This means that all cookies
>   set by Google Analytics for your
>   domain send data only to the servers
>   for your domain.

For varnish usage, this means that you can cache page responses because personal cookies are not set through Set-Cookie headers but generated by javascript equal for everybody. The cookies will however be sent with requests to your domain, and the current [default-vcl](http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/browser/bin/varnishd/default.vcl) says:

```
sub vcl_recv {

  ..

  if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
    /* Not cacheable by default */
    return (pass);
  }
}
```

It says it won't do a cache lookup if cookies are sent. So in your vcl_recv you should either 'unset req.http.Cookie' or do a lookup regardless of req.http.Cookie .

Comment: To what do you refer to when you say **personal cookies**? The cookies set by Google Analytics, or the cookies set by let's say a PHP application for logged in users?

Comment: _personal cookies are not set through Set-Cookie headers_ any external source confirming this?

Comment: What I meant with personal cookie is: a cookie-value that is specific for one user (e.g. a SESSION_ID). You don't want to give somebody's personal cookie to someone else (e.g. through caching the response). It is ok though to cache a (reference to) a script that generates a personal cookie on the client...

Comment: Session-ids are set through Set-Cookie headers, but Google Analytics does not set a Session on the GA domain

Comment: You're right, GA doesn't set cookies on the GA domain (that would be a third party cookie). Like the doc you linked says, the set them on your own server's domain, making them first party cookies.

Comment: But still those cookies **are** coming in through the headers right? Else, how would they be read by the GA code? If those cookies are still coming in through the headers, first-party or not, and Varnish sees those cookies in the request, it's not going to serve up a cached page, right?

Comment: Yep, the cookies are sent through the headers to your varnish. Varnish will by default not do a lookup. However, if you modify vcl_recv in your default.vcl file, you can instruct varnish to do a cache lookup regardless of the sent cookie headers.

Comment: To get back at your question 'How are the cookies read by the GA code?', it's not through the cookie-headers. There's no server code running at your server for GA. The cookies, set for your domain, are sent with some GA-javascript to the GA domain. I'm not aware of the exact mechanism but it could write a document.write('<img src="http://ga.com/?username=" + cookie.ga_username + ... ');, or include a javascript with the ga-cookie data as parameters. Look at the firebug resources-tab or the live-http headers plugin to find out about the exact data being sent to the different hosts...

Answer (score 4):

There's a good example here: https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRemovingSomeCookies

Basically you want to remove all GA cookies before Varnish sends the request to the backend with:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.Cookie) {
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|; ) *__utm.=[^;]+;? *", "\1"); # removes all cookies named __utm? (utma, utmb...) - tracking thing

    if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
        remove req.http.Cookie;
    }
  }
}
```

If no other cookies are left, Varnish will automatically cache and deliver pages to your visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analaytics sets and reads the cookies with JavaScript on the client side, so as long as you are not setting any conflicting cookies, Varnish caching doesn't affect it.

The cookies themselves might affect your Varnish caching, though -- as far as I remember, Varnish doesn't cache anything that has cookies and depends on them (that is, has a Vary: Cookie header). You might want to customize your VCL rules to make sure the Google Analytics cookies are not preventing caching.

Comment: Sorry that I just edited the question and if I made it a little bit harder to answer. Basically I'm after how stripping these cookies from the request affect recurring visitor statistics.

Comment: I can confirm that the visitors are getting tracked. Recurring visits? Not so much.