# PHP session_id() refresh on every request, $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] empty

Tags: php, session, cookies

I can't figure out why, but tried all answers/google.. I found nothing. Here's the situation:

**Localhost code**

```
    session_start();
    echo session_id();
    print_r($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
```

Result:

Consistent session_id() across app pages, and on page refresh. $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] matches the session_id()

**LIVE Server**

```
    session_start();
    echo session_id();
    print_r($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
```

Result:

session_id() changes on every request, page reload, or visiting another page. $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] is NULL/empty always. Same code used, on top of page. there's not any other content.

This problem has gave me a real headache, which server configuration or error could be causing this? Why PHPSESSID cookie is empty, I believe this is some how related to session_id() being reset on each request too?

Any help please guys!

**EDIT:
I made a simple 3 lines test file on local, remote server. It's not related to my code. The $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] is still empty and new session_id() on every refresh occurs on live host.**

ERROR_REPORTING SET TO ALL I get this on live host:

```
Notice: Undefined index: PHPSESSID in /home/vivaplug/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/test.php on line 5
```

**Google Chrome Headers**

**LOCALHOST**

```
Request URL:http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/test.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=68b7m4arpsacks4aetgmd3rs93
Host:localhost
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 05 Nov 2013 07:10:51 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.16
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.16
```

**REMOVE SERVER**

```
Request URL:http://vivaplugins.com/dev/wp-content/plugins/test.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:vivaplugins.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Age:0
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 05 Nov 2013 07:07:49 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Advanced Hosting by http://www.unixy.net/varnish
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Cache:HIT
X-Cache-Hits:2
X-Cacheable:YES
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.20
X-Varnish:1984840969 1984839805
```

Comment: Check if the session id cookie is sent in the response first

Comment: These 3 are lines of codes only. default session_start() should not it create one session id across pages/refreshes (it works ok on localh) the same on live server does not work.

Comment: cool. Could you please now check what I proposed in the first comment?

Comment: Sorry, how? :$ ..............

Comment: take firebug, chrome dev tools, fiddler or any other http sniffer and see the response headers.

Comment: Ok, i will do that - but thought this is helpful for you to debug - the /tmp session save path on server is always empty.. maybe that's related to the issue

Comment: `phpinfo()` and check session save path

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I pasted the HTTP header log from localhost/vs server. I can see some differences could you locate my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check session.use_cookies in your php.ini file. Must be set to 1.

Comment: It is on. On both environments. I think this is related to Varnish maybe. Do not know. But session_id() is setting. the PHPSESSID does not appear in http headers like on localhost

Comment: Yes, Varnish can indeed be the cause. Did not see it in the first place when scanning through your headers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474863/how-cookies-affect-varnish-caching It should be configured to pass through all cookies. Do you have access to the Varnish config?

Comment: No, I do not. I do not get the PHPSESSID and the session_id() keep changing on every request. Should I contact the host?

Comment: I would totally recommend that.

Comment: this is already on, but it still changes for me, every ajax request it id changes